# How to get input form type

Tags: symfony, twig

I want get form field type and set class fot field type

i try:

```
{# Form field row #}
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
  <div class="field-group{% if errors|length > 0%} error{%endif%}" id="fc-{{ id }}">
    {{ form_label(form, label|default(null)) }}
    <div class="field-item {{ type }}">
      {{ form_widget(form) }}
      {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        <div class="errors">{{ form_errors(form) }}</div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

But {{ type }} not working.

Comment: Because you've to set the type before using it.
Try adding 

    {% set type = type|default(your_type) %}

where your_type should be retrieved from "form.vars.types" to display whatever you want as a class for your fields.

Comment: Not, this is bad idea. I want get field type and add this type as class to "div" conainer.

Example: is field as "file" type. Result: <div class="file">{fieldWidget}</div>

Thank!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get the field type by using this:

```
{{ form.FIELD_NAME.vars.block_prefixes.2 }}
```

So if you got a field called message in your form use this:

```
{{ form.message.vars.block_prefixes.2 }}
```

For nested form field types use this:

```
{{ form.NESTED_FORM_NAME.FIELD_NAME.vars.block_prefixes.2 }}
```

**EDIT :**

To overwrite the basic form blocks do this in your template file:

```
....
{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block widget_attributes %}
{% spaceless %}
    id="{{ id }}" name="{{ full_name }}"{% if read_only %} readonly="readonly"{% endif %}{% if disabled %} disabled="disabled"{% endif %}{% if required %} required="required"{% endif %}{% if max_length %} maxlength="{{ max_length }}"{% endif %}{% if pattern %} pattern="{{ pattern }}"{% endif %}
    {% if not attr.class is defined %}
        class="{{ type|default('text') }}"
    {% endif %}
    {% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %}{% if attrname in ['placeholder', 'title'] %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue|trans({}, translation_domain) }}" {% elseif attrname == 'class' %}{{ attrname }}="{{ type|default('text') }} {{ attrvalue }}"{% else %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}" {% endif %}{% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock widget_attributes %}
{% block content %}
    ....
{% endblock %}
```

OR to get beter types:

```
....
{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block widget_attributes %}
{% spaceless %}
    id="{{ id }}" name="{{ full_name }}"{% if read_only %} readonly="readonly"{% endif %}{% if disabled %} disabled="disabled"{% endif %}{% if required %} required="required"{% endif %}{% if max_length %} maxlength="{{ max_length }}"{% endif %}{% if pattern %} pattern="{{ pattern }}"{% endif %}
    {% if not attr.class is defined %}
        class="{{ form.vars.block_prefixes.2 }}"
    {% endif %}
    {% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %}{% if attrname in ['placeholder', 'title'] %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue|trans({}, translation_domain) }}" {% elseif attrname == 'class' %}{{ attrname }}="{{ form.vars.block_prefixes.2 }} {{ attrvalue }}"{% else %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}" {% endif %}{% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock widget_attributes %}
{% block content %}
    ....
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This is bad idea (

There must be some variable that indicates the type of the field!

Comment: I have been trying to find that too, after a lot of var_dumps, foreach loops and a couple of hours spend reading classes this is what I found

Comment: Also the block_prefixes are variables of the field and they contain the field type of the `input` block

Comment: Thank, but each form_row must be a variable that indicate type of field! I want get this field type and add type as class to field container.

Comment: Thats why my answer states that you need to access the vars of a row by doing `form.FIELD_NAME` the FIELD_NAME is the same as the row name, I will edit my answer.

Comment: i have form theme: 

{% block form_row %}
<div id="field-{{ form.id }}" class="form-field {{ TYPE!!! }}">
  .....
</div>
{% endblock %}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19026/discussion-between-zhukv-and-matsrietdijk)

Comment: that numeric index variates depending on the type and most of the time 2 indicates the actual field name, not the guessed formType examples folow, showing output of `{{dump(form.vars.block_prefixes)}}` --> `0 =>string'form'
  1 =>string'text'
  2 =>string'textarea'
  3 =>string'_lifeCycle_note'` and `0 =>string'form'
  1 =>string'checkbox'
  2 =>string'_lifeCycle_ready'`. As I needed to know if dealing with checkboxes (to render label AFTER input) I used `{% if form.vars.block_prefixes.1 == 'checkbox' %}`

Comment: If I knew the field name, then I would know the field type :) So... +1 for effort, but this doesn't help me ;( But the answer below by A.L. works for me: `{{ form.vars.block_prefixes.1 }}

Answer (score 25):

The answer from MatsRietdijk is right, but as of Symfony 2.3 the index of the type seems to have changed from 2 to 1. As a result, `{{ form.vars.block_prefixes.1 }}` will return `checkbox`, `date`, `choice`, etc.

You can use it to [add a class to the form row](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#customizing-the-form-row) when [making application-wide customizations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#making-application-wide-customizations):

```twig
{% block form_row %}
    <div class="form_row {{ form.vars.block_prefixes.1 }}">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock form_row %}
```

Then you can apply CSS rules:

```css
div.form_row.text {color:Red;}
```

## Twitter Bootstrap

If you use Twitter bootstrap, you may have problems since the `.checkbox` class [exists in bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/64e81324261548a8de8cda5fde4b87d0f7a8f8fb/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1740). I suggest to use a prefix for Symfony forms rows:

```twig
{% block form_row %}
    <div class="form_row symfony_{{ form.vars.block_prefixes.1 }}">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock form_row %}
```

The rules in the CSS files will be different:

```css
div.form_row.symfony_text {color:Red;}
```

### Update

[Twitter bootstrap form theme is now included in Symfony 2.6](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme).

Comment: NOTE: on nested/included forms it returns the name of the entity (because this is actually the custom field type name). For example, on a regular text field: 
0=>form, 1=>text, 3=>_view_version_title

On a ckeditor field: 
0=>form, 1=>text, 2=>textarea, 3=>ckeditor, 4=>_view_version_content_content

But on a nested form: 
0=>form, 1=>viewVersion, 2=>_view_version

Answer (score 2):

`block_prefixes` is used to generate block names to display field (cf `FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock` method). The most specific existing block in template (generally `form_div_layout.html.twig` file) will be displayed.

So, the last item of `block_prefixes` is the id of your input, to allow you to override block for a specific field.

Previous item will be the item you need.

You can use this one : `$form->vars.block_prefixes[$form->vars.block_prefixes|count -2]` in smarty syntax.

Comment: ```formName.vars.block_prefixes[formName.vars.block_prefixes|length -2]``` in twig

Answer (score 1):

To avoid hardcoding the array index (1 or 2 depending on Symfony version), i've used the following:

```
{{ form.vars.block_prefixes | slice(-2,1) | first }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
{{ form.name.vars.original_type }}
```

E.g. from one of my templates

```
{% if myform.fieldname.vars.original_type == 'choice' %}
    <hr>
    {{ form_label(myform.fieldname) }}
    <p>Select a ...</p>
    {{ form_widget(myform.fieldname) }}
{% elseif myform.fieldname.vars.original_type == 'hidden' %}
    {{ form_row(myform.fieldname) }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: There is no option like this