# How to Understand the Variables Available in Custom Twig Form Template for each Input

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I understand [how to customize the twig template for forms per the documenation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

But I do not fully understand which variables are available in each block. I've studied the [original twig form template file](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig), but the scope of variables available in each block is not obvious to me yet.

For example, I followed the [tutorial to add an asterisk to the `form_label` block, if it's required](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#adding-a-required-asterisk-to-field-labels). But I do not want the asterisk if it's a hidden field (obviously... but the tutorials leave that part out). I am told hidden fields cannot ever BE required, but my hidden field required value is evaluating true...

This is how my hidden field is defined:

```
->add('timePublish', 'hidden', array(
    'required' => false
))
```

This still gets rendered in the HTML:

```
<span class="required" title="This field is Required">*</span>
<div id="view_version">
    <input type="hidden" id="view_version_timePublish" name="view[version][timePublish]" class="form-control">
</div>
```

So I don't know why that is happening in the first place. But given that it is, I would like to be explicit and skip the asterisk if it's type = hidden.

The `required` attribute is available in this block, but not the `type` of input:

```
{% block form_label %}
{{ parent() }}
{% if required is not empty and type != "hidden" %}
    <span class="required" title="This field is Required">*</span>
{% endif %}
{{ block('form_help') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately, `type` is not available, and throws an error:

```
Variable "type" does not exist in GutensiteCmsBundle:Form:fields.html.twig
```

I tried other variations like `form.type`, `form.vars.type`, `form.attr.type`, `form.vars.attr.type`, and `attr.type`, but none of these work either...

In addition to helping me understand this one variable name, can someone please reference comprehensive documentation for these variables (or give a summary of how to understand it myself), and help me understand how to dump this data for my own debugging in the future?

### UPDATE

The hidden input field was not causing the required asterisk to show up. Instead it was the included sub form. I have a primary form type `Form/Type/ViewType.php` which defines the main form, and includes several sub forms, e.g.

```
->add('version', new ViewVersionType(), array(
    'label' => false,
    'required' => false
))
```

Even though I had `'label'=>false`, the form_label was still rendering the asterisk. I had to also specify `'required'=>false` as well and that got rid of the asterisk. That seems really odd to me, that the included form IS allowed to have a required attribute (or at least that it defaults to true).

### Finding the Type

For Symfony 2.4 you can access type like this: `{{ form.vars.block_prefixes.1 }}`. This will show 'text', 'choice', etc. ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18786597/3334390)) It's not the HTML input 'type', but rather the symfony form type, so if you define a custom type (like a nested form) it will show the name of that, e.g. 'viewVersion'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your use case, I would not worry to much, since the hidden field type is not allowed to have required set to true (see [hidden Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/hidden.html)).

Regarding your question about the variables (from [Twig Template Form Function and Variable Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#twig-reference-form-variables):

> ... These variables are made available by the form rendering system. But more importantly, these are the variables that you can override when calling form_label (since in this example, you're rendering the label).
>
> The exact variables available to override depends on which part of the form you're rendering (e.g. label versus widget) and which field you're rendering (e.g. a choice widget has an extra expanded option). ...

On the same site, there is a list of variables, common to all form types (eg. `id`, `name`, `error`, ...).

But to correctly determine all available variables in the current twig context, you can use the answer, posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11500141/733368). Basically you can loop through all available variables with

```
{% for key, value in _context %}
    {{ key }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yet, oddly, it is setting a * in a span before the hidden field, which would suggest that `required is not empty`. `<div class="form-group"><span class="required" title="This field is Required">*</span><div id="view_version"><input type="hidden"         id="view_version_timePublish" name="view[version][timePublish]" class="form-control"
 /></div></div>`

Comment: @ChadwickMeyer How do you render the form field in your twig?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply! I got terribly sidetracked from this project by billable work. So I looped through `_context`, BTW, where do you know that `_context` is an available variable? (so much to learn and no clear way to learn it...) Anyway I see all the variables there and `required` is available. But when I do `{% if required is not empty %}` the asterisk appears still on the hidden field (see update to question).

Comment: Back to the original question: how do I check the `type` of input it is, e.g. 'text', 'hidden', 'select', etc.

Comment: For the record, the required asterisk was NOT coming from the hidden input, but from the included sub form... which evidently renders a label, even though label=>false. I had to specify required=>false as well e.g. `->add('version', new ViewVersionType(), array('label' => false, 'required' => false))`

Comment: And for the record, for Symfony 2.4 you can access type like this: {{ form.vars.block_prefixes.1 }}. This will show 'text', 'choice', etc. It's not the HTML 'type', but rather the form type, so if you define a custom type (like a nested form) it will show the name of that, e.g. 'viewVersion'.